# variations of "the places where"

Tags: relative-adverbs

> More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **the places where** people now fear to go. [Link](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=v0y0DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=more+interaction+in+public+places+and+human+traffic+on+the+sidewalks+would+increase&source=bl&ots=ynjvfR6MEu&sig=N1sCUqfnZvqzjp2Bp_mJjWQ4ppE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjss66siNvUAhXGebwKHRs2Dq4Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=more%20interaction%20in%20public%20places%20and%20human%20traffic%20on%20the%20sidewalks%20would%20increase&f=false)

As far as I know, the sentence above can be changed into:

> 1. More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **the places to which** people now fear to go.
> 2. More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **the places which** people now fear to go **to**.

In most cases, an antecedent like "place" can be omitted, but in this case, it is impossible because "the places" serves a role as an object.

> *More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **where** people now fear to go.* (wrong)

Also, I was wondering whether the following sentence is grammatically possible.

> More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **the places** people now fear to go.

Please verify my variations of the sentence.

Comment: As a learner: So, you are saying that "surveillance of where people now fear to go." cannot be the object? I think it's, for example, similar to "where people go"  which is a noun clause, hence it can take any roles that a noun can.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you for your comment. Your explanation makes sense. I haven't thought about the "where" clause itself can be an object for "of".

Comment: "Human traffic" doesn't seem correct here. I think you mean "foot traffic"? Human trafficking is a synonym for human slavery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence:

- More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of the places where people now fear to go.

We have two clauses - the main clause "*More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of the places*" and the defining relative clause "*where people now fear to go*" *(judging by the context)*. Commas are not used to separate defining relative clauses from the rest of the sentence.

The relative pronoun here is "**where**" that is used with places to make it clear which place we are talking about.

---

I'm not a native speaker but from what I know I can say the following:

1. More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of the **places to which** people now fear to go.

"**which**" like '**where**" here introduces the relative clause. If we include the **to-infinitive** we imply direction. The **to-infinitive** can be either before the *relative pronoun* or at the end of the *relative clause* here, both are fine:

- ...the **places to which** people now fear to go. (*slightly more formal*)
- ...the **places which** people now fear to go to. *(you can also use **that** instead of **which**)*

Compare to:

- ...the **places which/that** people now fear to visit.

---

2. More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of **where people now fear to go**.

Here the relative clause becomes the [**noun clause**](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/noun_clauses.htm). A noun clause is a clause that plays the role of a noun. There are quite many examples of such clauses *(noun clauses in bold)*:

- This is **where we sleep**.
- I often go to **where my mom used to go**.

> In a sentence, a noun clause will be a **dependent clause**. In other words, a noun clause does not stand alone as a complete thought.

---

3. More interaction in public places and human traffic on the sidewalks would increase surveillance of the **places people now fear to go**.

This is simply a [**reduced relative clause**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause). A reduced relative clause is a relative clause that is not marked by an **explicit relative pronoun** *(who, whose, whom, which, that, where, when, what)* or **complementizer** *(a word or morpheme that marks an embedded clause as functioning as a complement, typically a subordinating conjunction or infinitival **to**)*. When the relative pronoun is the object, it can be omitted. In this sentence "**where**" is omitted and the relative clause becomes a reduced relative clause:

- ...the **places *(where)* people now fear to go**.

However, with this example I see fit to include the **to-infinitive** at the end:

- ...the **places people now fear to go to**.